# What does a . (dot) do in PHP?

Tags: php

What does the following command do in PHP?

```
. $string   // ($string is something which I declared in the program)
```

Comment: A `.` is equivalent to a `+` in C++ or JavaScript, if that helps.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

On its own, that does nothing at all (it's not valid syntax).  However, if you have something like this:

```
<?php

$string1 = "Hello ";
$string2 = "world!";
$string = $string1 . $string2;

echo $string;

?>
```

You will see `Hello world!`.  The `.` is the string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 20):

Taken alone, this is a syntax error. The dot `.` is the [concatenation operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) that converts its arguments to strings and concatenates them. For example,

```
<?php
$string = "x";
$s = 42 . $string;
// $s is now "42x"
```

Comment: w3fools.com says: 
"Today, W3Schools has largely resolved these issues and addressed the majority of the undersigned developers' concerns."
So it is now pretty accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Your statement would throw back an error.

The "dot" is a string concatenator. That is, it helps you to combine strings together into another string.

Example.
$full = $part1 . $part2;

Concerning getting started: That's a difficult question. PHP.NET will be your functional looking site. Google-ing just about anything on PHP will direct you there. I'd look at getting a localhost setup of PHP/MySQL/Apache. If you're on a Windows machine, you can get a WAMP server setup.

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

This will drastically speed up your development and testing time. Don't try to FTP everything up to a Web server, as this approach will waste away 10-15% of your working time. Work smart - work local.

Find an existing project (Open Source) with a great community and just try to start something. For example, I recently created DogFriendlyOlrando.com based on WordPress. I was curious as to the abilities of WordPress. It was a fun little project and gave me a good understanding of WordPress' capabilities. You'll learn the most from just diving in and doing. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Two string operators are available. The first is the concatenation operator ('.') that returns its right and left argument concatenation.
Second is the concatenation operator of assignment ('.='), which adds the right-hand argument to the left-hand argument. For further details, please read [Assignment Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

Answer (score -2):

The output is displayed directly to the browser like as a given below:

```
. $string   // ($string is something which I declared in the program)
```