# PHP - echo inside an echo

Tags: echo, php

I have a PHP if/else statement. This is the code I'm trying to echo under an else condition.

```
<?php $locked = ForumData::is_topic_locked($post->topic_id);
            if ($locked->topic_locked == 1) {echo '<td align="right"><font color="#FF0000">Topic Locked</font><td>';}
            else { 
            echo '<td align="left"><a href="'.url('Forum/create_new_post?topic_id='.$post->topic_id.'&forum_id='.$post->forum_id.'').'"><img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro/images/forums/t_reply.gif"/></a></td>'; }
            ?>
```

The bit I'm interested to echo is this.

```
<img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>
```

If I try this... 'echo SITE_URL'

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'
```

But this doesn't parse the image, and if I try parsing anything else, it's giving me parsing errors, which I can't fix?

How can I therefore produce an echo inside another echo?

Comment: You have `}` at the end - where does it belong to? And the if-else statement is missing.

Comment: The } closes the else statement. I'll edit my main post for clarity.

Comment: I have problems to follow your quesiton, I can not reproduce that parse error. Probably that is to some other code. See here your code in many PHP versions: http://3v4l.org/b4NtM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why did you open a `<?php` tag again, you are already in echo line?

```
echo '<td align="left"><a href="'.url('Forum/create_new_post?topic_id='.$post->topic_id.'&forum_id='.$post->forum_id.'').'"><img src="'.SITE_URL.'/lib/skins/flyeuro/images/forums/t_reply.gif"/></a></td>';
```

and what is `SITE_URL`? Is that a variable, did you forget to put `$`?

---

echo prints out the string that you gave as parameter,

```
echo "foo";
```

As [@hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177571/php-echo-inside-an-echo/14177672#comment19647574_14177672) mentioned about it, `.` is used to [concatenate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6484983/603127).

```
$var = "foo"."bar";  //foobar
```

So you can use it in echo line,

```
$var = "foo"."bar";  //foobar
echo "foo "."bar ".$var // foo bar foobar
```

And It's not important weather variable defined as a string. It would be a [constant variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

```
define('SITE_URL', 'localhost:8080/phpvms'); 
echo "my website URL is ".SITE_URL; //my website URL is localhost:8080/phpvms
```

Comment: Could you explain to me for future reference what the dots do in PHP if you don't mind? The SITE_URL is a string of the website address gained from a config.php file in a CMS. It is setup during the CMS installation.

i.e. define('SITE_URL', 'http://localhost:8080/phpvms');

Comment: A dot in PHP is used to concatenate two strings. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php - that `define` defines a constant (as a  string), so you can use the dots here to contanate strings with strings. In my answer I just use `echo` with multiple string expressions separated by a comma, that is similar but also different: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14177712/367456 - a bit special to `echo`.

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation, just got an example sorted and working to enhance my humble PHP knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember:

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"$url\">View</a>"; ?>
```

" and \

this!

Hope that's enough of a hint!@

Comment: Oh, is it that easy? Correct me if I'm wrong <img src="<?php echo \"SITE_URL\"?> ... ;>

Comment: Might be that you need the double quotes around the html.

Comment: maybe put the whole thing in an include file. might work as well. just adding my two cents.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for "hints", explain your answer like the rest of us or don't bother posting

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably solved this way:

```
echo '<td align="left"><a href="',
     url('Forum/create_new_post?topic_id=' . $post->topic_id . '&forum_id=' . $post->forum_id . '') ,
     '"><img src="', SITE_URL,
              #######################
     '/lib/skins/flyeuro/images/forums/t_reply.gif"/></a></td>';
```

In PHP you can use constants quite like variables, e.g. to output them. You don't need to stack echoes inside each other or something.