# Using echo within conditional statement

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

I'm using a conditional statement to check what language the page is on. It's fine when I just need to output HTML, but the particular line I need to translate already has an echo statement in it and I am unsure how to echo the whole statement.

The line:

```
<div class="timer-col"> <span id="days"></span> <span class="timer-type"><?php _e('days', 'framework'); ?></span> </div>
```

My code:

```
<?php
$mylocale = get_bloginfo('language');
if($mylocale == 'en' || $mylocale == 'en-US') {
    echo '<div class="timer-col"> <span id="days"></span> <span class="timer-type"><?php _e('days ', 'framework'); ?></span> </div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="timer-col"> <span id="days"></span> <span class="timer-type"><?php _e('dien', 'framework'); ?></span> </div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You're already in PHP with `<?php` and `?>` remove those from the echos.

Comment: You have php tags in php tags! (Use concatenation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: You may want to put each of those echo statements on two separate lines... If this is WordPress' [`_e()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e), it works differently than a returned string that can be concatenated. (e.g. by putting the `echo '<div ..>` part on one line, and putting the `_e(...)` part on another.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - echo inside an echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177571/php-echo-inside-an-echo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is WordPress and its [`_e()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) function, you may want to break up your echo lines into something like the following example:

```
<?php
$mylocale = get_bloginfo('language');
if($mylocale == 'en' || $mylocale == 'en-US') {
    echo '<div class="timer-col"> <span id="days"></span> <span class="timer-type">';
    _e('days ', 'framework');
    echo '</span> </div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="timer-col"> <span id="days"></span> <span class="timer-type">';
    _e('dien', 'framework');
    echo '</span> </div>';
}
?>
```

This is because `_e()` does not return a string *(that normally could be used with string concatenation)*. Instead, `e()` simply prints out translated text *(without returning anything)*.

I've noticed that if I try to use `e()` inside of a string, I get unexpected placement results of where `e()` ends up echoing the translated text.

Comment: Hmm thanks, that makes sense. For some reason now all the timers are reading as the day timer.

Comment: It works! Thank you, I forgot to change the span id's to reflect the correct  unit.

Comment: @vytfla Glad to hear it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

```
<?php
$mylocale = get_bloginfo('language');
if($mylocale == 'en' || $mylocale == 'en-US') {
    echo '<div class="timer-col"> <span id="days"></span> <span class="timer-type">'. _e('days ', 'framework').'</span> </div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="timer-col"> <span id="days"></span> <span class="timer-type">'. _e('dien', 'framework').'</span> </div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I did, but it made all the text inline and work funny.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to write your echo statements something like this:

```
echo '<div class="timer-col"> <span id="days"></span> <span class="timer-type">' . _e("days", "framework") . '</span> </div>';
```

With single quotes around the HTML echoed parts, double quotes inside the single quotes, and PHP concatenated with '.'

See also: [PHP echo inside echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477025/php-echo-inside-echo)

Comment: This puts the text outside of the span.