# How do I rewrite an PHP echo inside a PHP echo?

Tags: php, wordpress, get, echo

I want to place this code:

```
<?php echo Sabai::_h($entity->getAuthor()->email);?>
```

inside of this code:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( 'email@example.com', 32 ); ?>
```

where it says `email@example.com`. Can someone write this so I can understand?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( Sabai::_h($entity->getAuthor()->email), 32 ); ?>
```

Or:

```
$email = Sabai::_h($entity->getAuthor()->email);
<?php echo get_avatar( $email, 32 ); ?>
```

Comment: The first code simply places the email on top of a no picture avatar

Comment: Then maybe there is something wrong with the get_avatar function.  Could you share more details about your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try out in this way. as ocanal said.
[PHP echo inside echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177571/php-echo-inside-an-echo)
taken from his example

```
     echo '<td align="left"><a href="'.url('Forum/create_new_post?topic_id='.$post->topic_id.'&forum_id='.$post->forum_id.'').'"><img src="'.SITE_URL.'/lib/skins/flyeuro/images/forums/t_reply.gif"/></a></td>';
```

or you can also refer this link for your reference.
[How to write php echo inside echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477025/php-echo-inside-echo)

please modify according to your code.

Comment: im not sure how, im new at this