# How to add PHP variable in SELECT Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in add value in SELECT query.

```
$sql=("SELECT `image` FROM `testtable`");
```

The output: 123.jpg

But I want output: 127.0.0.1/home/galery/123.jpg

So I tried:

```
$path='127.0.0.1/home/galery/';
.........

$sql=("SELECT $path+`image` FROM `testtable`");
```

But it's not working.

Comment: have you saved this value in your database..??

Comment: if not then you should concatenate your output value with path ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this.

**Method 1:**

Use string concatenation to join the path to the result from the SQL:

```
$path = '127.0.0.1/home/galery/';
$sql = "SELECT `image` FROM `testtable`";

// Run the query...

$result = $path . $sql;
```

In php, string concatenation is performed with the [`.` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6484968/604687). Also [see here](https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

**Method 2:**

The second method is via the [`CONCAT` SQL function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-concat-function.htm):

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT('" . $path . "', `image`) FROM `testtable`";
```

Or:

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT('{$path}', `image`) FROM `testtable`";
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5368890/604687) for the difference between these options.

Comment: Your first example in Method 2 is incorrect, as wrapping `$path` in single quotes will make it parse as the literal `$path`, so you'd have to remove the single quotes or use the second example, which doesn't actually need the curly braces around $path, but those are useful for readability.

Comment: And with that edit, +1 for pretty much touching on every sane method of answering.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql=("SELECT CONCAT('$path',`image`) FROM `testtable`");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation like below....

$sql=("SELECT".$path."+`image` FROM test")

Here, text in double quotes are string