# any one know what the function of dot (.) in this code

Tags: php

```
<a class='btn btn-danger' href='delete.php?sesi=user&id=".$data['username']."'>Hapus</a>
```

can someoen explain the function of dot(.)

Comment: it concatonates the php - this seems to be written in one php string. it basically tells php that "the next part here, is php code, and not a string", and then the string starts again after the next dot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a . (dot) do in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484968/what-does-a-dot-do-in-php)

Comment: Maybe also look at [What does this symbol mean in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: Concatenation? Post a full php code extract, not something cut in the middle of nowhere if you want someone to understand what it is about...

Answer (score 0):

It's not a function. It's [concatenation operator](http://just%20https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to connect between **strings**

I took this example from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
<?php
  $a = "Hello ";
  $b = $a . "World!"; // now $b contains "Hello World!"

  $a = "Hello ";
  $a .= "World!";     // now $a contains "Hello World!"
?>
```