# Is it possible to use period (dot) in a PHP function name?

Tags: php

I am using a template of a "certificate of completion" for online courses for my website.

On the template it has placeholder function names where presumably values would be pulled from database or elsewhere.

For example:

```
Certificate of Completion
This is to certify that
$student.getFullName()
has completed the course
$course.getName()
with score of $grade.getPoints()%
```

To my understanding you cannot use a period in the middle of a PHP variable of function name.
Can someone explain what this convention is [ i.e. $student.getFullName() ] and whether it is valid PHP or just some invalid pseudocode?

Comment: Replace `.` with `->` you are trying to get a child element of a class like a function, not merge 2 strings together

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a . (dot) do in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484968/what-does-a-dot-do-in-php)

Comment: The dots look like javascript notation instead of PHP

Comment: You were right aynber, I assumed it was a PHP var based on it starting with $ but turns out it's a js variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## the answer

to call a method in php, use `->` not **`.`**

#### (.) using in PHP

for combining two strings, like:

```
$str1 = "hello ";
$str2 = "world";

$str12 = $str1.$str2;
```

> hello world

#### (.) using in js

It's called dot-notation, you can access properties on an object by specifying the name of the object, followed by a dot (period) followed by the property name. This is the syntax: `objectName.propertyName;`

Comment: Thanks.  It turns out the placeholder variables were JS and I mistook them for PHP because I wasn't used to seeing a JS variable begin with "$".